# Observe RUs consumed when using CosmosDB's Cassandra API?

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to learn how many RUs were consumed when executing a query using the Cassandra api on CosmosDB?

(My understanding is normal API returns this in an additional HTTP header, but obviously that does not work with CQL as wire protocol..)

Comment: You can find this in the `RequestCharge` field in the incoming payload that comes back after you execute a query via an SDK call.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to get request charge for specific CQL queries in Cosmos is to turn on diagnostic logging. Then each query you run will result in a diagnostic log entry like this.

```
{ "time": "2020-03-30T23:55:10.9579593Z", "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<your_subscription_ID>/RESOURCEGROUPS/<your_resource_group>/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB/DATABASEACCOUNTS/<your_database_account>", "category": "CassandraRequests", "operationName": "QuerySelect", "properties": {"activityId": "6b33771c-baec-408a-b305-3127c17465b6","opCode": "<empty>","errorCode": "-1","duration": "0.311900","requestCharge": "1.589237","databaseName": "system","collectionName": "local","retryCount": "<empty>","authorizationTokenType": "PrimaryMasterKey","address": "104.42.195.92","piiCommandText": "{"request":"SELECT key from system.local"}","userAgent": """"}}
```

For details on how to configure Diagnostic Logging in Cosmos DB see, [Monitor Azure Cosmos DB data by using diagnostic settings in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-monitor-resource-logs)

Hope this is helpful.